# Increase number of concurrent connections to a ip address

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a ubuntu box and I can open 20,000 concurrent connections to this box. The maximum number of connection is about 25k but it is not always get there. However, if I create another network interface like eth1:0. I can bind another 20k connection to the new ip address.

In my testing I bind to 3 ipaddress and able to open 60k connections to this box. Why each interface is limit to about 20K connections? Is there a way to increase it?

Thanks,
Sean Nguyen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
```

should show you the allowable range of ports to use for making connections from your box.

```
sysctl -w 'net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=10000 65000'
```

should allow you to change that range. Make sure the range you specify doesn't conflict with any service you use in that box.

Comment: I don't think it matters if the range conflicts with services on the box, the kernel should be smart enough to work it out.

Comment: @MarkR: The kernel can work it out if the service is running and has bound the port - but if the service is temporarily down then its port could be assigned as an ephemeral port, which would prevent it starting up.